# Linear Map and matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can all linear maps $f:V \rightarrow W$, where $V$ and $W$ are K-vector spaces be represented by matrix multiplication of some matrix, $A$?
Or does it depend on the field you are working with? Thanks

Comment: When you say matrix multiplication, did you think of where the entries of the matrix come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are both finite dimensional, yes. If either is infinite dimensional, what does a matrix even look like?